# Translation of maximal solution to ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Im given the equation $$\left( 1+\left( \frac{c}{y}\right)^2\right)\dot{y}=4$$where $c>0,y>0$ and $t\in \mathbb{R}$ and the initial condition $y(0)=c$. I have found the maximal solution $y(t)=2t+\sqrt{c^2+4t^2}$ for all $t\in \mathbb{R}$. I'm then asked to argue that any other maximal solution can be obtained by translation of the $y(t)$ I have found. However I'm not sure what they mean by translation and how one would even argue this. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I deleted the answer because it's more of a comment now. I have to admit I am not aware of any other use of the world "translation" for ODEs, but I did some digging and found some stuff about Lie groups and symmetry groups, involving translations of the ODE/solution so it can be solved that way. I guess this is definitely something you haven't heard off, right?

Comment: No unfortunately not, but thank you for trying!

Comment: I guessed so. Well, trying to make a guess from the Laplace operator property of
$$\mathcal{L}\left\{e^{at}f(t)\right\} = F(s-a)$$
all I can assume is that they may want you to investigate whether $y(t) := e^{at}y(t)$ is a solution.

Comment: @Rebellos I think I have found the definition of translation: https://i.imgur.com/6pziHzm.png where an autonomous equation is an ODE that doesn't depend on $t$, which is what we have. If you still are willing to help I would appreciate it.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning. Can you name the reference?

Comment: Ordinary Differential Equastions by Jacob Schach Møller.